# Andengine gles1 texture packer extension

Tags: andengine, game-engine, texturepacker

I'm developing a game and I wanna use texture packer extension. But I can't use. I don't know how to add my project? and I guess it because of being gles1.

Comment: Why don't you use GLES2-AnchorCenter? It's in active development and it has texturepacker built in.   https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine

Answer (score 1):

@Shikima is correct.  There is no support for `TexturePacker` in GLES1 and there likely never will be as it isn't in development and hasn't been for quite some time.  Best to refactor your project so you can use live code.